Forest of maximal weight edges in weighted graphs
Consider a weighted undirected graph $G=(V,E,\omega)$ and assume for simplicity that all edges have distinct weights.
For all $v$ in $V$, we denote by $n(v)$ the unique neighbor of $v$ such that $\omega(v,n(v)) = \max_{w\in N(v)} \omega(v,w)$.
Then, the subgraph $F=(V,E')$, in which $E'$ is the set of edges $(v,n(v))$ for all $v$, is a forest (a set of trees).
Question: what is the name of this object, and where does it appear in the literature?
Variants appear for instance in:

A Distributed Algorithm for Minimum-Weight Spanning Trees
Watershed Cuts: Minimum Spanning Forests and the Drop of Water Principle
A Graph Theory Interpretation of Nodal Regions

However, it is not viewed as a fundamental weighted-graph concept in these papers. Are there any other papers dedicated to it? For instance, are there known properties of graph $G$ (its structure or its weights) that induce some properties on forest $F$ (like its number of trees or their depths)?

This is Nearest neighbor graph (min instead of max), but not sure there are studies of graph-theoretic properties in general graphs.

Most objects don't have a name.  This doesn't have any name that I'm familiar with.  It doesn't really matter all that much what the name is, anyway.  A name is just a means of communication.  A rose by any other name still smells just as sweet.
It could be called the nearest neighbor graph for $-\omega$.  But I'm afraid that doesn't really tell you all that much...
"Fundamental" is a matter of opinion (or values).
